# django DISTINCT: COUNT vs len

Tags: mysql, sql, django

I have a model M with some fields, and three of them have ordering defined. Lets call them a, b, c. So I have ordering = ["a", "b", "c"].

My problem is:

```
n = M.objects.values_list ('a', flat=True).distinct()
n.count() --> 217
len(n) --> 26580
```

How is this possibles?

I use Python 2.7, Django 1.6 and MySQL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation on `distinct()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) addresses this point:

> If you use a `values()` query to restrict the columns selected, the columns used in any `order_by()` (or default model ordering) will still be involved and may affect uniqueness of the results.

If you override the default model ordering with your own it should work:

```
n = M.objects.order_by('a').values_list('a', flat=True).distinct()
```

(Though there are some more caveats in the documentation if `a` is a related field.)

Comment: Thanks, but still, how count is different from len?

Comment: @EllaShar: Well, we're talking about two different SQL statements and two different methods of counting. You'd have to look at the generated SQL to really understand it. The many results for `len` makes sense because your `distinct()` is being applied to `a, b, and c` instead of just `a` like you wanted. The `COUNT` version doesn't seem to suffer from that problem.